# Vbscript - Click an untypical button on website

Tags: html, vbscript

how do I make vbscript click a button on a webpage which, according to "Inspect Element" is represented by this code:

```
<td class="a" id="logout" onclick="BtnClickPreHandler(this);" onmouseover="HoverOn(this)" onmouseout="HoverOff(this);" title="Log out">
    <img class="d" id="logout_d" src="/style/2011/images/buttons/logout_up.gif" style="display: none;">
    <img class="a" style="" id="logout_a" src="/style/2011/images/buttons/logout_up.gif">
    <img class="h" style="display: none;" id="logout_h" src="/style/2011/images/buttons/logout_up.gif">
    <span id="logout_s" class="a">Log out</span>
</td>
```

I was able to click normal buttons with something like `appIE.Document.getElementsByName("Submit").Item(0).Click`, however in this case I cannot reference the object correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tee logout action is effected by a mouse-click on the `<td>` element, so just do the same from your code, like so:

```
appIE.Document.getElementById("logout").Click
```

Comment: Well, the problem here is that I get the error "Object Required: Document.getElementById(...)"

Comment: Break-up the expression by storing intermediate values to determine which is returning `Nothing`.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant - however, I tried this `objButton = appIe.Document.GetElementByID("logout") msgbox typename(objButton)` and the result was "Null".
When I tried the same for a previous button that I am able to click with `appIE.Document.getElementsByName("loginSubmit").Item(0).Click`, the result was "String".
However, there the code was <button name="loginSubmit" type="submit">

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "button" may be an image, try something like:

```
For Each i In IE.document.images 
    If i.src Like "*/buttons/logout_up.gif" Then i.Click 
    else
    end if
Next i
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem to do anything...:( Isn't this element the key here? `onclick="BtnClickPreHandler(this);`